# Can't get the right $(this) element with onclick. Trying to use :not for input inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

That was one hard title to write with a good explanation.

I got the following html:

```
 <div class="requestItem clearfix">
       <div class="col-sm-2">Great info goes here yo.</div>
       <div class="col-sm-2">Some info goes here</div>
       <div class="col-sm-2">Date goes here.</div>
       <div class="col-sm-1 pull-right">
            <div class="buttons">
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn dark-button tiny-button"  />
                    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn dark-button tiny-button margin-top" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row extraInfo">
                <div class="col-sm-12"> 
                   some random info
            </div>
        </div>  
  </div>
```

with the following JS:

```
$('.requestItem').click(function () {
    console.log($(this));
    if ($(this).is(':input')) {
        alert("input clicked"); return;
    } else { $(this).children('.extraInfo').slideToggle(); }
});
```

What should happen: When i click one of the buttons which is of element input, the toggle should not happen.

What happens: $(this) is always the parent div, requestItem. I get that this can be a normal problem since the requestItem is wrapped around the button, however, i need to know if the button was clicked since i don't want to toggle a slide then.

Thanks in advance!

**AFTER HELP: This is what i ended up with:**
Hope it helps someone else too.

```
$('.requestItem').click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is(':input')) {
        $(this).children('.extraInfo').slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(this)` is the element you've assigned the event. Use `$(event.target)` to get the actual clicked element.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `event.target`

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pr7e9wqq/1/

Basically, since your listener is on the containing element `div.requestitem`, that is the `this` context for the callback function. Your click event on the input bubbled up to the containing element (which you were listening on). Remember that `this` will always be set to the element that matches your selector.

Comment: On the slideToggle, you need to still be using `$(this)`. The `.target` only needs to be used on the compare. Otherwise, nice work!

Comment: Good catch, fixed. Other answer is more solid anyway.

Comment: Does not make yours wrong or unhelpful. +1 now that it's fixed!

Answer (score 2):

By default, `this` in a jQuery click handler returns is the element that it's bound to (in this case, `.requestItem`). To get the element that got clicked, use `e.target`:

```
$('.requestItem').click(function (e) {
    console.log($(e.target));
    if ($(e.target).is('input')) {
        alert("input clicked"); return;
    } else { $(this).children('.extraInfo').slideToggle(); }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c6zbwq03/